# Create a new category in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse-plugin, categories

When I want to create a new *Category* or *Command* for an extension point from *Extension* tab in the *Plug-in Manifest Editor*, most of the tutorials and books tell to right-click on `org.eclipse.ui.view` and choose *New -> Category*.

However, when I right-click and then select *New*, the only choice I get is *Generic*.

Anyone knows how I can create a new *Category* from *Extension* tab?

I'm using Eclipse Indigo *Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there is something wrong with PDE... You'd better use one of the following package:

- "Eclipse Modeling Tools, 274 MB",
- "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers, 227 MB",
- "Eclipse Classic ".

Comment: I'm using a plug-in that requires this version from Eclipse. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: You can use these package, and install plugins that you needed. Use the menu Help--> Install new software...  and choose an update-site... For example, if you are using Indigo, you can choose the "Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo", and then you can find plugins you need.

Comment: As of 2018  you can download eclipse IDE for plugin development which has these functionalities.